# As soon as I plug in the LAN cable WiFi stops working - even though it has higher priority

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-networking

As suggested here: [How can I force Windows 7 to give my LAN (wired) conection priority over my WiFi?](https://superuser.com/questions/321324/how-to-give-network-choice-priority-to-lan-other-than-wifi-in-windows-7)

[image]

... I checked that WLAN has higher priority over LAN.

Nonetheless when I plug-in the LAN cable (no Internet access over LAN) Chrome stops giving me from the good stuff.

Also `netstat -rn` seems to indicate that WLAN already has highest priority:

```
C:\Users\rvo>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
 17...a4 db 30 d8 32 90 ......Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
 12...a4 5d 36 ce 06 17 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
 18...16 db 30 d8 32 90 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #2
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #4
===========================================================================
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I set the WLAN interface metric from automatic to 5 as suggested here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/

Somebody knows why this is necessary beyond defining the priorities?

Comment: Metrics is what defines the network "priority" as it were. A lower metric interface is used over an interface with a higher metric.