# How to force Remote Desktop via firewall rules to use LAN instead of WLAN?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, firewall

[WLAN has higher priorities than LAN but Remote Desktop seems to still use WLAN.](https://superuser.com/questions/783783/as-soon-as-i-plug-in-the-lan-cable-wifi-stops-working-even-though-it-has-highe)

I tried to achieve this by setting up a firewall rule but this does not seem to do the trick.

Here is what I tried:

1) Outgoing rule restricting MSTSC.exe to LAN.

- Interface type selected is LAN
- Chosen "action": "allow connection"

  In this case RD does not get connection even when I disable WLAN explicitely.

2) Outgoing rule banning MSTSC.exe from WLAN.

- Interface type selected is WLAN
- Chosen "action": "block connection"

  In this case RD works when I disable WLAN explicitely.

Common settings:

Both cases refer to only the program: %SystemRoot%\System32\mstsc.exe

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi again. I believe that you can try `c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe` (without asking to expand environment variables) - or whatever the specific path of mstsc is (you can find with `where mstsc`).

Comment: Also a setting you might have to look at is the profile - whether you are on Domain / Private / Public profile for each of the interfaces (WLAN might not be Domain, but LAN is and the rule you created applies only to Domain).