# Disable Wireless when connected to the wire (LAN mode)? Best strategy and advice

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, thinkpad, group-policy

Is there a new possibly method in GPO (Group Policy Management) to automatically turn off wireless when a network cable is plugged in and to turn in on when not cable is detected.

*Using the following systems: Windows 7 and ThinkPad machines.*

In other research, technicians recommend:

- Look at the BIOS
- Unfortunately there is still no GPO? vogues talk! Anything is possible.
- Write a Windows Service
- There are third party service (Wireless AutoSwitch, Accessity called 1NET) but it'd be better through GPO or economic

Comment: IIRC this is the default on windows 7.  Each connection has a metric. (Usually a cost but windows bases this cost on max. theoretical speed.) So when you have a 54Mbit wireless and plug in 100Mbit wired then access to your default gateway (and thus to the Internet) should switch over.  Also see this post: http://superuser.com/questions/321324/how-can-i-force-windows-7-to-give-my-lan-wired-conection-priority-over-my-wifi and its answers.

Comment: update to at least Windows 8, here Windows uses fasted one automatically, also if you started a transfer over wifi and plugin a LAN cable, Windows will switch to faster LAN cable without a need to restart transfer.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There are no settings in Group Policy that will disable a wireless network connection when a cabled connection is made.

This setting doesn't exist for good reason. Automatically disabling your wireless connection would only make sense if the newly established cabled connection was to the same network segment.  But this isn't a safe assumption: Suppose you're accessing the Internet via your wireless connection, then connect via Ethernet cable to an isolated network without Internet connectivity.  How would Windows know whether you want to keep or forfeit your Internet access?

For this and other reasons no such Group Policy setting exists.

Comment: I found a better solution via GPO. For example if we choose to deploy script via group policy, we can assign computer startup script or user logon script. Therefor, developing a script? that would have been a better answer. Thanks! Any other answers, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS:

1. Go to BIOS by press F12 during reboot.
2. Power Mgt ==> wireless radio control == > check the "Control WLAN RADIO & Control WWAN RADIO".
3. Reboot the laptop.
4. Now it will

[Or develop a login Script, Click Here.](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/278-disable-wireless-on-lan-script)

Answer (score -1):

This is not true. the following GPO will do this \Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Windows Connection Manager. Double-click Prohibit connection to non-domain networks when connected to domain authenticated network.

Comment: This assumes the WiFi in question is not a domain/business WiFi which is likely is, although its a good setting to point out :)